# Dynamically including multiple files within php for image descriptions

Tags: php

Working on implementing image descriptions to a php run gallery and can't seem to figure out how to call each text file for each individual image. I would need to place a div in the code for the image and then call the include.

```
   //total number of images
   $total = 77;

   //max number of thumbnails per page
   $max = 9;

   //what image do we want to start from?
   $startcount = $_GET["start"];

   //if there is not a defined starting image, we start with the first
   if(empty($startcount))
    {
   $startcount = 0; 
  }

   //start off the loop at 1
   $loop = 1;


   //start the loop
   while($loop <= $max)
    {

   //for the picture labels
   $num = $startcount + $loop;

   if($num > $total)
    {
     $num = $num - 1;
     break;
    }

   // Add class="last" to every third list item
   if(is_int($num / 3))
    {
     $last = ' class="last"';
    }
   else
    {
     $last = "";
    }

   //the code for the image
   echo '

        <li'.$last.'><a href="images/portfolio/pic-'.$num.'.jpg" rel="milkbox[gall1]"><img src="images/portfolio/thumbs/pic-'.$num.'-thumb.jpg" width="256" height="138" alt="Thumbnail of image '.$num.'" /></a><div>'.$num.'</div></li>';
```

I see that I can call the text files by number using '.$num.' (I have 77 individual text files with a phrase in each) but how do I tell it to call the files?

Comment: 77 text files, descriptions, images... what?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the description files are named something like "description_$num.txt", you can simply use [`readfile`](http://php.net/readfile).

```
  echo "<li${last}><a href='images/portfolio/pic-${num}.jpg' rel='milkbox[gall1]'>
          <img src='images/portfolio/thumbs/pic-${num}-thumb.jpg' width='256' 
               height='138' alt='Thumbnail of image ${num}'/>
        </a><div>";
  readfile("description_${num}.txt");
  echo '</div></li>';
```

Note that you don't "call" files in PHP, you either [include](http://php.net/include) them (which interprets them as scripts) or read them (which dumps them to the output).

Answer (score 0):

For each file you need to do something like that:

```
<?php 
$f=fopen($file,'r'); 
$data=''; 
while(!feof($f)) 
    $data.=fread($f,$size); 
fclose($f); 

// do whatever you want with the file content.

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made use of file_get_contents, and split the output a bit so you can more easily modify it:

```
<?php
$total = 77;
$max = 9;
$startcount = $_GET["start"];
$loop = 1;
if(empty($startcount)) $startcount = 0; 

while($loop <= $max)
{
    $num = $startcount + $loop;
    if($num > $total)
    {
        $num--;
        break;
    }
    $last = ($num % 3 == 0 ? ' class="last"' : '');

    $output = "<li $last>";
    $output .= "<a href=\"images/portfolio/pic-$num.jpg\" rel=\"milkbox[gall1]\">";
    $output .= "<img src=\"images/portfolio/thumbs/pic-$num-thumb.jpg\" width=\"256\" height=\"138\" alt=\"Thumbnail of image $num\">";
    $output .= "</a>";
    $output .= "<div>";
    $output .= file_get_contents("textfile-" . $num . ".txt"); // assuming this is where you want the phrase
    $output .= "</div>";
    $output .= "</li>";

    echo $output;
}

?>
```